# Packaging JavaScript Functions

Tags: javascript

I'm working to create a shared package of JavaScript functions. At this time, I'm trying to use them like this:

**/app/index.js**

```
const myPackage = require('../myPackage');

myPackage.function1();
myPackage.myScope.function2();
```

The above successfully loads `myPackage`. However, when I attempt to run `function1`, I receive an error that says: "TypeError: myPackage.function1 is not a function". My code in the "package" is organized like this:

```
/myPackage
 index.js
 root
   function1.js
 myScope
   function2.js
```

The code looks like this:

**index.js**

```
require('./root/function1.js');
require('./myScope/function2.js');
```

**function1.js**

```
exports.function1 = function() {
  console.log("Doing stuff in function1");
}
```

**function2.js**

```
exports.function2 = function() {
  console.log("Doing stuff for function2");
}
```

I could understand `function2` not working because, there's nothing putting it in `myScope`, which I don't know how to do. However, I don't understand why `function1` isn't running. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate bergi's answer, you need to have the following in your `index.js` file:

```
// file: index.js
exports.function1 = require('./root/function1.js').function1;
exports.myScope2 = {
    function2: require('./myScope/function2.js').function2,
};
```

Because `require('./root/function1.js') == exports object in function1.js`. So if you
have multiple functions in your `function1.js`, you have to go like this:

```
// file: index.js
exports.function1 = require('./root/function1.js').function1;
exports.function11 = require('./root/function1.js').function11;
exports.function111 = require('./root/function1.js').function111;
...
```

A shortcut of that can be:

```
// file: index.js
Object.assign(exports, require('./root/function1.js'));
```

**On the other hand:** you can set the exports object to be your function:

```
// file: function1.js
module.exports = function() {
    console.log("Doing stuff in function1");
}
```

Then you can have the following in your `index.js` file:

```
// file: index.js
exports.function1 = require('./root/function1.js');
exports.myScope2 = {
    function2: require('./myScope/function2.js'),
};
```

Here `require('./root/function1.js') == function1 from function1.js`. Hope that explains
the issue.

Comment: @MunimMunna What does the `/app/index.js` file look like then? When I try this, I still get runtime errors.

Comment: `index.js` looks exactly like the first code-block in the answer, just copy paste. What error do you get?

Comment: @MunimMunna I see "TypeError: myPackage.function1 is not a function". I added a `console.log(myPackage)` just before the call to see what was there. I see this: `{ function1: undefined }`

Comment: @MunimMunna I should mention that if I use `require('./root/function1.js')` instead of `require('./root/function1.js').function1` I see `{ function1: {} }` from the `console.log`. However, I see the same error.

Comment: @MunimMunna I got it working. I had to add `module.exports = function1;` to the bottom of function1.js.

Comment: That's what **On the other hand** section says in the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `index.js` doesn't export anything. You will have to do

```
Object.assign(exports, require('./root/function1.js'));
exports.myScope = require('./myScope/function2.js');
```

Or maybe better have your `function1.js` and `function2.js` modules export the function itself (`module.exports = function() { … };`) instead of creating a property, then use

```
exports.function1 = require('./root/function1.js');
exports.myScope = {
    function2: require('./myScope/function2.js'),
};
```

Comment: If I use `exports.function1 = ...`, I then have to use `myPackage.function1.function1` in my code. I just want to use `myPackage.function1`.

Comment: @user687554 You'd do that if you change the export inside the `/root/function1.js` - a file with that name would be expected to export only that function, not a module object containing that function.

Comment: So, "function1.js" would be changed to just `function function1() {
  console.log("Doing stuff in function1");
}` Is that correct?

Comment: No, to `modules.export = function function1() { …};`. The important part is omitting the property from the assignment.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Which assignment? What should index.js look like?

Comment: I was talking about the `function1.js` file.

Comment: @user687554 according to this answer just copy paste any of the 2 code blocks to your `index.js` file and it will work as you are expecting.

Comment: @MunimMunna I want to keep the code blocks in their respective files though. I want to do this for organizational needs.